# Markov Chain Monte Carlo doesn't converge

Tags: estimation, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo

I have a synthetic measurement model that looks like this,

$$ x(t) = e^{j u t \frac{4}{\lambda}}, $$ $\lambda$ is a constant.

$$ z(t) = x(t) + n(t) $$

The quantity $j = \sqrt{-1}$, the imaginary unit. The noise $n(t)$ added to this signal has two components as well, one real and one imaginary part.

Where $n$ is a zero mean white Gaussian noise with a variance of $\sigma_n^2$. $$ n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_n^2) + j \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_n^2) \right) $$

From this measurement model, I take only some measurements for analysis of the MCMC method.

I want to estimate the value of $u$ from this model. The noise $n$ has both a real and an imaginary part. I assume that the noise variance $\sigma_n$ is known already.

I use a Gaussian prior for $u$. The parameter $u$ is not complex; it is a real quantity.

$$ p(u) = \mathcal{N}(\mu_u, \sigma_u) $$

The likelihood I take as,

$$ \log(p(z|u)) = -\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x})^T  K^{-1}  (\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x}) $$

Where $\mathbf{z}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are vectors with the dimension of $t$. The value $K$ is defined as,

$$ K = \sigma^2 \times I, $$ $I$ is the identity matrix. So, $K$ is a real matrix dealing only with the known noise variance.

I separately compute the real and imaginary parts of the likelihood as,

$$ \log(p(z_{Real}|u)) = -\frac{1}{2} (real(\mathbf{z}) - real(\mathbf{x}))^T  K^{-1}  (real(\mathbf{z}) - real(\mathbf{x})) $$

$$ \log(p(z_{Imag}|u)) = -\frac{1}{2} (imag(\mathbf{z}) - imag(\mathbf{x}))^T  K^{-1}  (imag(\mathbf{z}) - imag(\mathbf{x})) $$

The problem I face is that the likelihood not only has a real, but also has a imaginary component. In the acceptance criteria of Matropolis Haistings algorithm, I now add the real and imaginary likelihoods in log scale. Code is given later in this post.

If the ground truth has $1000$ samples, only $50$ samples are available as measurements. The samples are placed in a way that there is a definite gap between sets of samples. For example, $5$ samples placed together in time $t$, there is a huge time gap of $95$ sample space and again another $5$ samples are available. The samples in time $t$ available can be represented as this.

$$t = N.k.dT + \sum_{i = 1}^{M}i.dT$$

Here, $N = 100$, $M = 5$ and $k \; \epsilon \; [0, 1, 2, ....]$.

A working example is given below.

```matlab
%% HD signal generator

close all;
clear;

SNR_db = 20;                % Noise is added with a given SNR in dB
SNR = 10^(SNR_db/10);       % SNR in linear scale


lambda = 1;             

r0 = 0;                     
u = 1;                      % Ground truth u

N = 100; 
M = 5;

K = linspace(1, 10, 10);

Nt = K(end) * N;                 % Number of Truth samples (N * M * 20)

dT = 0.1;                  % t step
r(1) = r0;                  

Z(1) = exp(1j * 4 * pi/lambda .* r(1)); 

for i = 2:Nt
    r(i) = r(i - 1) + u * dT;
    Z(i) = exp(1j * 4 * pi/lambda .* r(i)); % Ground truth samples
end

Noise = sum(abs(Z).^2)./(Nt .* SNR);         % Finding Noise power and ...
                                             %noise variance with the data and given SNR
sigma_n = sqrt(Noise);

Z_model = Z + sigma_n .* (randn(1, Nt) + 1j .* randn(1, Nt))./sqrt(2); % Adding complex noise 


%% Available samples [Measurement model with only a few samples]

  


Z_model_re = reshape(Z, [N K(end)]); 
Z_avail = Z_model_re(1:M, :); 

Z_avail_vec_ = reshape(Z_avail, [M * K(end) 1]); % available samples for measurements


Z_avail_vec = Z_avail_vec_ + sigma_n .* (randn(1, length(Z_avail_vec_)).'+ 1j .* randn(1, length(Z_avail_vec_)).')./sqrt(2);

for k = 1:K(end)
    t(:, k) = (k - 1) * N + [1:M]; % This for loop calculates the t instances of the available samples
end

t_avail = reshape(t, [length(Z_avail_vec) 1]) .* dT; % vectorize the available time instances


%% MCMC parameters in a structure var

% E is the structure having options for MCMC

E.n = 1;                            % Number of variables to be estimated

E.E0 = [1.3];                    % Initial value of u 
E.sig = [50000];                    % Initial value of the Std of the prior of u 


%% This section has MCMC algorithm 
No_iter = 10000; % Number of iterations

[accepted, rejected, itern, E_new] = MHu(E, No_iter, Z_avail_vec, t_avail, r0, sigma_n);

%% Plot MCMC outputs 


for i = 1:E.n

    
   figure(1000+i);plot(rejected(:, i)); hold on; plot(accepted(:, i)); % Accepted and rejected values
   
   burnin = round(0.25 * length(accepted(:, i)));                      % 25% of the data is taken as burnin
   figure(2000+i); histogram(accepted(burnin+1:end, i), 100);          % histogram of accepted
   burninrej = round(0.25 * length(rejected(:, i)));                   % Burnin for rejected
   figure(3000+i); histogram(rejected(burninrej+1:end, i), 100);       % Burnin for accepted
   mu_re = mean(accepted(burnin+1:end, i));                            % Mean of accepted 
   rej_re = mean(rejected(burnin+1:end, i));                           % Mean of rejected
end
```

```matlab
function [accepted, rejected, itern, E] = MHu(E, iter, data, t_avail, r0, sigma_n)

%% Inputs:

% E - Struct of MCMC options 
% iter - number of iterations
% data - data available
% t_avail - t instances of the data
% r0 - start position of the target - assumed to be known
% sigma_n - noise standard deviation - assumed to be known

%% Outputs:

% accepted - accpetd values
% rejected - rejected values 
% itern - iterations at which we accept a value
% E - the new Struct of MCMC options after processing - A new E.sig is
% updated


    u = E.E0; % save the initial value in u
    accepted = zeros(1, E.n); 
    rejected = zeros(1, E.n);
    
    
    itern = 0;
    
    for i = 1:iter
        disp(i);
        [u_new, punew, pu] = TMu(u, E.sig);     % u_new is a new sample drawn for u 
                                                % prior probability of u_new
                                                % prior probability of u 
        
        u_lik = LLu(u, data, t_avail, r0, sigma_n, pu); % Likelihood of u wth data
        u_new_lik = LLu(u_new, data, t_avail, r0, sigma_n, punew); % Likelihood of u_new with data
   
%% Acceptance Logic

        if (acceptance((u_lik), (u_new_lik)))
            
            
            accepted = [accepted; u_new];
            itern = [itern i];             
            u = u_new;
        else
            rejected = [rejected; u_new];
        end
    end
end
```

```matlab
function [unew, punew, pu] = TMu(u, Esigma)

    for i = 1:length(Esigma)
        unew(i) = normrnd(u(i), Esigma(i), 1); % Draw a new value
        
        
        pu(i) = normpdf(u(i), u(i), Esigma(i)); % Find the prior probability of x
        punew(i) = normpdf(unew(i), u(i), Esigma(i)); % Find the prior probability of y
    end 
end
```

```matlab
function ret = LLu(u, data, t_avail, r0, sigma_n, pu)

    lambda = 0.03;
    
    r(1) = r0; % initial position of the scatterer
    Z_model(1) = exp(1j .* 4 .* pi/lambda .* r(1)); % First sample echo model 
    
    for l = 2:length(t_avail)
            r(l) = r(l - 1) + u .* (t_avail(l) - t_avail(l - 1)); 
            % This for loop calculates the model
            % samples from the available t steps $t_avail$
          Z_model(l) = exp(1j .* 4 .* pi/lambda .* r(l));
    end
    
    Nt = length(data);
   
    K = eye(Nt, Nt) .* sigma_n.^2; % Noise diagnoal matrix with size length(t_avail) x length(t_avail)
   

%% Real and imaginary part likelihood 

    ret_re = log(pu) -Nt/2 .* log(2*pi) - 1/2 * (real(data) - real(Z_model).').' * inv(K) * (real(data) - real(Z_model).');
    ret_im = log(pu) -Nt/2 .* log(2*pi) - 1/2 * (imag(data) - imag(Z_model).').' * inv(K) * (imag(data) - imag(Z_model).');
    
    ret = ret_re + ret_im; % Total likelihood (multiplication of real and imaginary likelihoods in linear scale)
    

end
```

```matlab
function ret = acceptance(u, u_new)
   
        alpha = exp(u_new - u);
        rnd = rand;
        
    if alpha > rnd
        ret = 1;
    else
        ret = 0;
        %accept = rand;
        %ret = (accept < exp(x_new - x));
%         ret = 0;
    end
end
```

Total truth samples: 1000
Total measurement samples: 50
True u : 1 (as per the code above)

I start with a very big proposal standard deviation (`E.sig` in the code as 50000). The problem is that if I run $10000$ iterations, only a very few samples are accepted like only $10$. It doesn't converge. As the `E.sig` is super high, does it take a long time to converge? If you see the rejected values, it seems to oscillate at some point with a constant mean and feels like it is stuck at a local minima probably?

The plot of accepted and rejected values are shown below. Here, the accepted values are only 12 so they are not visible. The pattern for the rejected values kind of gives an impression that it is unable to reach a good value for $u$. So, I feel the final value of accepted values could be a local minima and getting out of this point is harder for the algorithm. I have put a histogram of rejected and accepted values as well. The final value of $u$ is $6.26 \times 10^{4} $ and it occurs at iteration number $4878$ which is much before $10000$.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Next I show a case with `E.sig = 1`. However, in a practical scenario, one would like to start at a higher value. Is there a way to avoid this? Here also the acceptance rate is so low (only 10 out of 10000).

[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE: With answer 2**

I have tried the values of the second answer.

$\lambda = 1$, $u_{true} = 0.01$, $\sigma_n^2 = 0.01$, $dt = 0.1$. Start value of $u_{start} = 0.014$ and the proposal distribution of $u$ has a standard deviation of $u_{std} = 0.0001$. The results are below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have $110$ accepted values out of a $10000$ iterations.

I also plot a likelihood in log for various values of $u$ as in the second answer. It looks similar but not smooth.

[image]

Comment: *"The problem I face is that the likelihood not only has a real, but also has a imaginary component."* Could you explain where this imaginary component comes from?

Comment: What is $j$ in the expression $e^{j u t \frac{4}{\lambda}}$? Is it the imaginary unit? If $x$ is a complex number how do you add the noise to it? Only noise is added to the real component?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Yes, $j$ is the imaginary unit $\sqrt(-1)$. The noise $n$ as I mentioned is added to both real and imaginary parts. Like $n(t) = n_r + j n_i$

Comment: @CfoutPiO could you clarify this in your post. The $j$ as imaginary unit is not known to everyone (I only thought about it halfway you post when you talked about imaginary component, and until that point I thought it was a type or unexplained integer). Also, it is not clear that the Gaussian noise has two components.

Comment: The Gaussian prior for u is this also a complex variable? Otherwise, if you only use a single real variable as parameter, then the only thing that $u$ does is change the frequency but not the amplitude. And to change the phase one would need an intercept term as well. For instance, you would use $$x(t) = e^{(j u t + j v + w ) \frac{4}{\lambda}}$$ Without this it can make the problem [ill-posed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem) or otherwise difficult. This can happen for instance because you might have a shift in time or some other measurement error....

Comment: ... you seem to be focusing on only a single part of the complex variable. Then this problem becomes like fitting a wave function. This is problematic because you can have a perfect fit (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/476326/164061) for an example image that demonstrates this). Along with the lack of a necessary intercept term and amplitude this can make that your posterior drifts away from the $u$ that you were expecting and that you get a very low acceptance rate (because the sampling is done in a region with very low likelihood).

Comment: I edited the question. I have added all the details. I am looking at your comments and trying to understand. I may have some further question.

Comment: The Gaussian prior of $u$ is real. The $u$ is a real quantity.

Comment: It would be better if you would provide a complete reproducible example. There are currently several problems and it is unclear whether these are the cause of the problems with convergence. Examples of unclear cases is why you do not simply multiply the likelihood functions since the noise terms are independent $p(a,b) = p(a)p(b)$. Then you will have one single comparison with the `rand` instead of two.

Comment: Another thing is that the real and imaginary parts of $\log(p(z|u))$ is not the same as using the real and imaginary parts for $z$ and $x$. $$\log(p(z|u))_{real} \neq \log(p(z_{real}|u))$$

Comment: I corrected the real and imaginary parts. It is actually reproducible. I am a bit poor in statistical notations. I will try with a multiplication of the likelihood.

Comment: *"It is actually reproducible"* I can not reproduce this problem. Your example doesn't provide enough information for that.

Comment: *"I corrected the real and imaginary parts"* In your code you write `real(p(z, u_2))` and that seems like you take the real part of the complex function, but that is different from dealing with the real and imaginary part of $z$ seperately.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I code it in a different way so I just write the logic here to not confuse. However, I messed it up a bit. Now, it is clear which probabilities I use. The real and imaginary parts are separately treated.

Comment: How does the function `p` know that you are dealing with the real part or the imaginary part? It is namely not just the vecyor $z$ that you take the real/imaginary part of, but also the vector $x$....

Comment: ...to avoid all these sorts of confusion it is better if you include the entire procedure and something that can be reproduced by others. At the moment we keep making slow steps based on tiny errors and there is no complete overview of what you are doing.

Comment: I have gone through your code now and I have a good idea what can be going one. I want to write an answer similar to LudvigH's answer and my earlier comment about the problem of fitting a wave function. In order to make my answer stay close to your situation I am wondering how you are updating `E.sig`. Your histogram shows proposals in the order of $10^5$ which is due to that large `E.sig` and that, of course, results in a lot of rejections because you are sampling in a region with low probability density. (with a smaller `E.sig` the problem will be different).

Comment: I actually play with different values of `E.sig`. I know for a likelihood having a very low periodicity, `E.sig` has to be really small and the starting point also has to be closer to the actual solution. I want to avoid it. I want to start at a random point and converge to the global maxima. So, that is why I kept `E.sig` too high just to check if it comes out of local maxima points. Sadly, probably it needs like infinite iterations or so.

Comment: In principle, the signal is 100 times stronger. because Noise = Signal Power / (SNR * number of samples). Then, I take a square root of the Noise and add it to the signal. So, it is not exactly 100 times stronger, it is more than that based on the number of samples we have.

Comment: I got it, I misread your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell if your problem is due to mistakes inyour implementation or if it is about the actual estimation problem. We don't have any working code to inspect. I implemented a working example for you -- see code below. I have also made an analysis of your problem, as described below.

The code implements Metropolis-Hastings with Brownian motion proposal. I tinkered quite some time with initialization and step size. The solution is very much dependant on these values. In the code, they are called `u` and `step size`. The values in the code currently comes from a kind of manual annealing burn in -- I started with a wild guess for `u` and large `step_size`. At the end of that run, I wrote down the final `u`, and restarted the whole process at that `u`, but with smaller `step_size`. And repeated again and again.
In the early runs, the acceptance rate is ca 0.5%. By the end, it is ca 50%. Reducing the step size further makes the samples autocorrelated, so I stopped here with the parameters in the code below.

The reason why this kind of annealing scheme is needed is because of the nasty periodic structure of the likliehood with sharp local maxima. I plotted the log likelihood and the histogram of samples to illustrate that. The histogram is extremely narrow and quite hard to see in the plot using this axis limits, but quite nice to work with interactively.
[image]

If the step size is too large, it will propose in the low-likelihood regions too often and get rejected. If the step size is too small, it get stuck in one of the small "bumps". The periodicity of the plot is due to aliasing.
Run the code with differenet initializations and zoom around, and I think you will get a nice feel for it. :)
I also played around with different noise levels, sample sizes, prior parameters etc. The conclusions changes with that of course. But in this low noise setting I have in the code below, the prior don't matter at all.

N.B. The plot shows the **log** likeliehood, since we are working with really small likelihoods. The use of logarithms can be crucial to get numerical stability.

The code also produces a different diagnostic plot
[image: output plots. sharp histogram. low autocorrelation. quick burn-in. reasonable predictions]

that tells us that the burn in period is long enough, that the autocorrelation between samples (after burn-in) is low, and that when I pick the expected posterior parameter, and generate synthetic data with it, it looks quite okay.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(999)


#
# Generate data for the observed time indices
#
dt = 0.1
M = 5
N = 100
u_true = 0.01 # the true u-value, to be estimated
lamda = 1 # assumed known
noise_variance = 0.01 # assumed known
t = np.array([N*k*dt + i*dt for i in range(5) for k in range(10)])
n_data = len(t)
x = np.exp(u_true*1j*t*4/lamda)
n = (
        np.random.standard_normal(size=n_data) +
        1j*np.random.standard_normal(size=n_data)
    )*np.sqrt(noise_variance)/np.sqrt(2)
z = x + n

#
# Configure and Initialize Metropolis-Hastings
#
sigma2_u = 1 # the variance of the gaussian prior
mu_u = 0     # the mean of the gaussian prior
proposal_step_size = 0.0001  # adjusted in manual "annealing" process
u = 0.014                    # initialization
get_proposal = lambda u:  u+np.random.standard_normal()*proposal_step_size # proposal is brownian motion
burn_in_samples = 500
mcmc_steps = burn_in_samples+ 2000

def log_proposal_density_ratio(u_new,u):
    """The proposals density is symmetric, so the ratio is always 1, and the log(1) = 0 always"""
    return 0

def log_likeliehood(u):
    """ compute the log likeliehood of this parameter
    as in
        log(p(z,u)) = log(p(u)) + log(p(z|u))   
    """
    x = np.exp(u*1j*t*4/lamda) #compute the predicted data sequence under this u
    n = z - x                  # compute the observed noise, assuming this predicted sequence
    n_real_std = np.real(n) * np.sqrt(2) / np.sqrt(noise_variance) # this is a vector of standard-normal distributed values, under the model assumptions
    n_imag_std = np.imag(n) * np.sqrt(2) / np.sqrt(noise_variance)
    ll1 = -0.5*np.log(2*np.pi) - 0.5*n_real_std**2                 # this is a vector of log likliehoods per observation
    ll2 = -0.5*np.log(2*np.pi) - 0.5*n_imag_std**2
    log_p_z_given_u = ll1.sum() + ll2.sum()
    log_p_u = -0.5*np.log(2*np.pi*sigma2_u)-0.5*(u-mu_u)**2/sigma2_u
    return log_p_u+log_p_z_given_u


#
# Run Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm
#
ll = log_likeliehood(u)
us = np.zeros(mcmc_steps)
did_accept = np.zeros(mcmc_steps)
for step in range(mcmc_steps):
    u_new = get_proposal(u)
    ll_new = log_likeliehood(u_new)
    accept_ratio = np.exp(ll_new - ll + log_proposal_density_ratio(u_new,u))
    rand = np.random.random()
    if rand < accept_ratio:
        u = u_new
        ll = ll_new
        did_accept[step] = 1
    else:
        did_accept[step] = 0

    us[step] = u

#
# Do diagnostics on the results
#
print(f"After burn in, {did_accept.mean():.1%} of the proposals were accepted.")
print(f"There are {len(np.unique(us[burn_in_samples:]))} unique values in the kept samples")

fig,axs = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
axs=axs.flatten()
variation = us[burn_in_samples:]-us[burn_in_samples:].mean()
variation /= np.linalg.norm(variation)
corrs = np.correlate(variation,variation,mode='same')
axs[0].plot(corrs[len(corrs)//2:],label='correlogram of samples')
axs[0].legend()
axs[1].plot(np.arange(burn_in_samples),us[:burn_in_samples],color='C3',label='burn in')
axs[1].plot(np.arange(burn_in_samples,mcmc_steps),us[burn_in_samples:],color='C2',label='kept samples')
axs[1].legend()
axs[2].scatter(t,np.real(x),label='real(x)')
axs[2].scatter(t,np.real(z),label='real(z)')
axs[2].scatter(t,np.real(np.exp(us.mean()*1j*t*4/lamda)),label='real(estimated x)')
axs[2].legend()


#
# Explanation plot
#
urange = np.linspace(-0.05,0.2,500)
lls = np.array([log_likeliehood(u) for u in urange])
fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True)
axs=axs.flatten()
axs[0].hist(us[burn_in_samples:],label='MCMC samples (after burn in)',alpha=0.7)
axs[0].hist(us[:burn_in_samples],label='MCMC samples (burn in)',alpha=0.5)
axs[0].axvline(us.mean(),label=f'MCMC mean ={us.mean():.3f}',color='C1',linestyle='dotted')
axs[0].axvline(u_true,label=f'true u = {u_true:.3f}',color='C2',linestyle='dotted')
axs[0].legend()
axs[1].set_ylabel("Log Likliehood")
axs[1].set_xlabel("u")
axs[1].plot(urange,lls)
plt.show()
```

In summary:

- I can't tell from your description if you had any problems with the implementation. It seems from the discussion with Sextus Empiricus that there might be misundrestanding about how to compute the likeliehood.
- Metropolis Hastings can be used on this problem to generate samples from the posterior, if appropriate step size is used and it is initialized around a suitable local optimum.
- The use of logarithms may be critical, as log likelihoods can be as small as -2500 .
- For my number of data points and noise levels, the prior didn't have any notice'able effect. It can matter in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will change my question clearly again with a working example.

Comment: I have tried your values in my code and I updated my plots in the question.

Comment: Thank you for adding a working example. It seems you have some minor mistakes (e.g. you double count the effect of the prior, you don't generate data as described in the question etc) but I think the MH implementation is ok.

Comment: So I really don't have much more to add to the answer than what I already gave. The Log Liklelihood is super rugged, and a brownian motion proposal will only work for tiny step sizes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also found some fundamental errors of time axis and I am fixing it. What do you mean by I double count the prior?

Comment: I had one more doubt. The `proposal_step_size` and `sigma2_u` are two different things in your code? Why is so? I thought the values of $u$ that is tested in the MCMC algorithm should come from a distribution like the prior. You have chosen a distribution, but you are not testing many values from that distribution. You are only checking with a very small width.

Comment: I used your code and I have understood it. I think the idea of having a very small step size works like magic. However, I still don't know why the step size is different than the sigma2_u. I always thought the values are drawn from a distribution that is predefined. And, the parameters of that distribution can be changed based on the iterations.

Comment: the prior (you stated in the question it is gaussian) is part of the bayesian methodology. the proposal distribution comes from the MH algorithm, and you can use MH as a frequentist or in a bayesian way. I suggest you read and do exercises from http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/BDA3.pdf to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

If I try to reproduce the data I get this as the sample:

[image: data]

Because these are many cycles (1000), the fitting of this with a wave function requires a very small margin of error in the parameter $u$. When a small difference is made, then this has already a large influence on the position after 1000 cycles.

Below you see this with an example where every 20 time-ticks a sample of 5 is taken. In the first image with the green curve the frequency is changed by a factor 5% and this has little effect for small times $t$ on the left but a large effect on the right.

For a few special ratios in the frequency, like 1.25, which is the red curve below in the second image, some of the points in the wave function coincide and you get a relatively higher likelihood. This makes that you get multiple peaks in the likelihood function.

[image: example of increasing error]

The consequence is a likelihood and prior that is very sharp.

[image: likelihood]

[image: posterior]

Your proposal function has a much wider range and so you are gonna sample mostly in the region with non-zero probability. What you need is a first good estimate of the $u$ and the bandwidth of the prior. Then you can get a better function that proposes new samples within the range.

---

Is still have to make the MCMC part for this question, but how do you compute the prior? I can not find this easily in your code. You have this function `function ret = acceptance(u, u_new)` but it seems to compare `exp(u_new - u)`, which is the likelihood ratio but not the ratio of the posterior.

---

It might possibly be easier to use the variable $X(t)-X(t-1)$ (and since you observe batches of 5 consecutive times you get batches of 4 of those differences). Then you get that a small change in $u$ has not such a large effect on the likelihood. It may also be more realistic in cases that are not so steady. With your current likelihood function you are saying that the ground truth $e^{iu4\pi/\lambda t}$ has no variability after hundreds of cycles and that the process is very steady. So currently you assume that the error distribution is the same after hundreds of seconds as after 1 second.

---

R-code

```
######
######

set.seed(1)
### Parameters for sampling
###
### Nt = N*S numbers are the ground truth
### every N numbers there are M numbers sampled
N = 100
M = 5  
S = 10   
Nt = N*S

### Parameters for signal
dt = 0.1
u = 1
lambda = 1

### Parameters for noise
SNRdb = 20
SNR = 10^(SNRdb/10)
sigma = 1/sqrt(SNR)


### create variables

t = c(1:Nt)*dt            ### time variable
Z = exp(1i*4*pi/lambda*u*t) ### signal
sigma = sqrt(sum(abs(Z)^2)/(Nt * SNR)) 
epsilon = 1/sqrt(2) * (rnorm(Nt, 0, sigma) + 1i * rnorm(Nt, 0, sigma))   ### noise
X = Z + epsilon
selection = rep(N*c(1:S),each = M) + rep(1:M,S) - M ### id's of S times M consequitve id's with gaps of N

plot(X) ### view the variable

loglikelihood = function(uf,t,X) {
 x_fit = exp(1i*4*pi/lambda*uf*t)
 residual = x_fit-X
 error = sum(Im(residual)^2 + Re(residual)^2)
 return(error)
}
loglikelihood = Vectorize(loglikelihood, "uf")

posterior = function(uf,t,X) {
  prior = dnorm(uf,1.3,10^3)
  exp(-1*loglikelihood(uf,t,X))*prior
}
posterior = Vectorize(posterior, "uf")


u = seq(0.7,1.3,0.0001)
plot(u,loglikelihood(u,t[selection],X[selection]), log = "", type = "l")


u = seq(0.7,1.3,0.00001)
plot(u,posterior(u,t[selection],X[selection]), log = "", type = "l",
     ylab = "posterior(u,X) [not scaled to integrate to 1]")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I do here is that I treat the real part and imaginary part separately for the likelihood function. So, $K$ is also used separately twice. I think only by taking the real part of the signal, I can do the analysis without bothering about the imaginary part. The noise variance is the same for the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Is it a good idea to look for complex normal distribution? Can it use  the complex signals as it is to find a likelihood at the end?

Comment: @CfourPiO the complex normal distribution of the complex n-vector $z$ is equivalent to a multivariate normal distribution of the real 2n-vector $Re(z), Im(z)$ (the other way around is not true in general). So you do not really need to use the complex normal distribution. Possibly it might be convenient for your case if you want to describe a particular correlation structure.

Comment: I am deleting this answer for the moment. I placed this answer because your likelihood function already looked very weird and seemed to be at least some problem (with the imaginary part). Could you clarify in more detail the steps that you took. It is difficult to reproduce your problem. For instance it is not clear how you computed the likelihood exactly and which MCMC method you used or what software and function call you used and in what way you compute the proposals for new draws (e.g. a problem is if your proposal function is very different from the posterior that you try to sample from).

Comment: Very nice insight. With your answer, I was able to back track and find the limitation in physics that caused this. It was really insightful. Thank you!

Comment: You could tackle this problem with some manual work, but if you are looking for some very reliable and effective code to tackle this situation automatically, then you could search for some fancy proposal function that is a Gaussian mixture of three normal distributions and has three modes. One central mode that makes the sampling within the peaks, and also a mode at plus 5% and a mode at minus 5%, which ensure that you don't get stuck in a local optimum.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking of something similar. Thanks a lot!